# Embed Twitter Feed without Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Were trying to embed a twitter feed onto our footer on a site built on an eCommerce platform.

Unfortunately the system doesn't allow external JavaScript calls as they "might interfere" with the store.

Can anybody recommend a way to embed a live twitter feed, without using JavaScript?

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5706)

> The embed code for the tweet has fallback behavior for environments without Javascript -- you lose some of the functionality since the tweet's validity won't be verified via Javascript, but the HTML chosen for the embed code should fallback smoothly.

Was first hit on google for your title.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments cOlz, i had read this, unfortunatly (which I should have made clearer) it's not that javascript calls are dissabled, but that they are not allowed... It's also not on our servers, but the systems providers servers.

Comment: You say "doesn't allow external JavaScript calls", so how about instead of using external JS, just copy paste twitters [widget.js](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) into your code? Another thing: does your ecommerce platform have widgets or addons? I'm sure someone wrote a twitter addon.

Comment: The embed code generated by Twitter today seems to require JS.

Answer (score 0):

The embed code for the tweet has fallback behavior for environments without Javascript -- you lose some of the functionality since the tweet's validity won't be verified via Javascript, but the HTML chosen for the embed code should fallback smoothly.

You can also try this : [http://codingowl.net/blog/twitter-feed-without-javascript/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140220144949/http://codingowl.net/blog/twitter-feed-without-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution,

iframe to a file on a server elsewhere